# pass variable from node to bash exec

Tags: node.js

I am using this pattern to execute bash scripts:

```
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function myBash() {
    try {
        const { stdout, stderr } = await exec("echo hi");

        console.log(stdout);

    } catch (err){
       console.error(err);
    };
  };
```

How can I pass the variable greeting to the exec command - non working:

```
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
const greeting = "hello";

async function myBash(greeting) {
    try {
        const { stdout, stderr } = await exec("echo", greeting);

        console.log(stdout);

    } catch (err){
       console.error(err);
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const greeting = "hello";

async function myBash(greeting) {
  try {
    const {
      stdout,
      stderr
    } = await exec(`echo ${greeting}`);
    console.log(stdout);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  };
};
myBash(greeting);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

`exec` will execute a command line (a string) by feeding it to a shell. You have two options:

- Not great in this use-case: use `exec` with a string that incorporates arguments:

  ```
  exec(`echo '${greeting}'`);
  ```

  or equivalently

  ```
  exec("echo '" + greeting + "'");
  ```

  Note that this breaks down if the argument contains single quotes, so they need to be sanitised or properly escaped if you do not trust the arguments.
- Much better in this case: use a function that is designed to pass arguments directly to an executable - `execFile`:

  ```
  execFile("echo", [greeting]);
  ```

  Note that this does not invoke shell; here it actually executes `/bin/echo`, not the bash builtin `echo`. It also does not parse any arguments, so wildcards, variables etc will not be substituted.